# No rule to make target 'startup.s'

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that keeps throwing an error:

`make: *** No rule to make target 'startup.s', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`

I've created some variables:

```
OUT_DIR = ./Build

SOURCE_DIR = ./Src

SOURCES  = main.c
SOURCES += startup.s

OBJECTS  = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS += $(SOURCES:.s=.o)
```

and here are my targets:

```
all: setup $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Done!" 

setup:
    @mkdir -p $(OUT_DIR)

%.o : $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$@
    @echo

%.o : $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.s
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OUT_DIR)/$@
    @echo
```

Why doesn't make find the target for startup.s, it's supposed to use the last target `%.o : $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.s`

Comment: thats not a target. %.o would be target, and make can't find one that matches .s files. $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.s would be the dependency. basically you need to make a rule for %.s files

Comment: @DTSCode The `.s` files are sources. They aren't getting built. The fact that make is seeing it as a target is the problem in and of itself.

Comment: @EtanReisner right that is because he lists it as a dependency with no recipe for building

Comment: @DTSCode Right and **that** is the problem. He shouldn't be listing it (in a place that it isn't) as a dependency at all. He should either not list it explicitly at all (as I indicate in my answer) or list it from the correct location (which the `%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.s` target already does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a target for `startup.s`. You have a target that *uses* `.s` files (from the `$(SOURCE_DIR)` directory).

`startup.s` is supposed to be a file that already exists and that can be compiled *into* a corresponding `.o` file.

Your `$(OBJECTS)` variable doesn't contain what you think it does.

You *think* it contains `main.o startup.o` but it doesn't. It **actually** contains `main.o startup.s main.c startup.o`. (Each substitution reference only changes values that match. It passes unmatched values through directly.)

You need to add a `$(filter)` call to those lines to do what you want.

This is the problem. You are, accidentally, telling make to build a `startup.s` file in the current directory and it doesn't know how to do that.

As additional issues with this makefile your `%.o` rules do not create a file that matches the target pattern and this will confuse make. See [Rule 2](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/#rule2) of the Rules of Makefiles from the GNU Make maintainer. (Rule 3 is also somewhat relevant here.)

Comment: Ah! That's the issue, hanks @Etan